Safari 18 rendering bug - it doesn't hide element after removing from DOM
I try to hide element from DOM, using React conditional rendering
{isShowConversationBlock && (
        <div className={styles.conversationWrapper}>
          <ConversationBlock
            tab={type}
            entity={ConversationEntity.SitemapPageBlock}
            entityId={blockId}
            onClose={closeConversationBlock}
          />
        </div>
)}

Styles for conversationWrapper
right: 8px;
top: 8px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1100;

When I use Chrome it works as I expect
Safari behavior

Chrome behavior


As you can see, Safari leaves shadows on removed from DOM element, and I can't understand what the problem

Possibly relevant https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/17726.
